# Google Scholar Profile exists but not searchable

Tags: google-scholar

My Google Scholar Profile was searchable until yesterday. Now, It does not appear when I search my name (Amir Sagiv). When I (usual) Google it, the link is broken and I get a 404 code.

To be sure - the profile is there; when I log into Scholar I can view and edit my profile.

Seen anything like it?

Here is the broken link:
https://scholar.google.co.il/citations?user=zGndG2IAAAAJ&hl=en

Comment: Is your profile set to public? Click on the edit pencil and check if the "Make my profile public" checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to search for your name and return a Google Scholar profile with a different ID in the URL:
IL: https://scholar.google.co.il/citations?&user=fHFTU7EAAAAJ
US: https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=fHFTU7EAAAAJ

Is that you?
Is this also you? https://orcid.org/0000-0002-0831-216X

If those links look accurate for you, it looks like your profile is up. I'm not sure what would have caused the URL to change though. A different ID suggests a different account. I would expect that ID in the URL to remain stable for a specific account.

If that is not you, you may need to distinguish yourself online from another researcher with the same name. ORCiD is really great for helping researchers with this.

https://intercom.help/lean-library/en/articles/3214065-where-do-i-find-my-personal-google-scholar-id
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Google_Scholar_id

Comment: Hi @Diego I'm facing this issue 
https://orcid.org/my-orcid?orcid=0000-0001-6967-4765 ; 
https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=B8VoEywAAAAJ&hl=en ; 
My paper: https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=1m3Ow-gAAAAJ&sortby=pubdate&citation_for_view=1m3Ow-gAAAAJ:mlAyqtXpCwEC 
Verified Clg Email, Public Selected, Open-Access Paper, Not searchable, 1st paper in 2021.