# Google Scholar says profile "was not found on this server"

Tags: google-scholar

I have 2 publications on my google scholar profile. I recently found that I had 2 google scholar accounts and deleted the old one. Now when I'm trying to search for my name on google and go into google scholar I get

```
404. That’s an error.  The requested URL /citations?user... was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

If I go on google scholar and search for my name I can find my profile, but not through actual google search.

How can I fix this?
I found [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/173079/google-scholar-profile-exists-but-not-searchable) SE question similar but could not find how they solved it.

Comment: How long ago did you delete your other account? Could it be that you just have to wait a bit until Google figures it out?

Comment: Maybe 2 weeks ago?

Comment: Is your profile public? Have you added a verified institutional email ID?

Comment: Profile is public and email is verified

Comment: Are you sure the link you are clicking on Google Search is the correct one? You said you deleted one profile, perhaps Google Search had indexed that one and is still trying to reach it, and has not updated its index yet?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well. But it's been a couple of weeks already so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: You can just check the URL you are clicking on Google compared to the URL of your profile, are they the same?

Comment: Nope. Different users. It must be the old one then